# Editing drop-down doesn't fetch value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created a drop-down for categories and subcategory. It works fine when i submit the form, but when I edit the form, category field does not come with refilled data from the database, category drop-down come like it show in create form.

here is my edit:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category','Category:') !!}
    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control input-sm">
        @foreach($s as $k)
            <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('subcategory','Subcategory:') !!}
    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    // get the event
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    $s = Category::all()->where('parent_id','=','0');
    $r = Event::all();
    $daysOfWeek = unserialize(Event::find($id)->days_of_week);
    // show the edit form and pass the event
    return view('event.edit',compact('event','s','r','daysOfWeek'));}
```

I haven't used relations for the dropdown, I have used jquery and ajax to select subcategory after I select category. 
What can i do to get the value stored in database when I do edit form?

Comment: You question is not clear. can you explain more?

Comment: Usually, when we edit form, we see all the fields are filled. but the category drop-down does not show filled data, its empty in form like, we are filling for first time.

Comment: Its because you are not using 'selected="selected"' attribute for selected option

Comment: I tried added selected, but it is showing one more field `test` in dropdown

Comment: show me your code tried for this

Comment: ` <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}" selected="{{$m}}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>`  where ` $m = Event::find($id)->category;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99292/discussion-between-shweta-and-amit-rajput).

Comment: what is the value of $m?

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer thanks every one for help!

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category','Category:') !!}
    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control input-sm">
        @foreach($s as $k)
            @if($k['id'] == $m)
            <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}" selected="{{$m}}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>
            @else
            <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('subcategory','Subcategory:') !!}
    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control input-sm">
        @foreach($subcat as $k)
            @if($k['name'] == $subid)
                <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}" selected="{{$subid}}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{ $k['id'] }}">{{ $k['name'] }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    $s = Category::where('parent_id','=','0')->get();
    $r = Event::all();
    $m = Event::find($id)->category;
    $subid = Event::find($id)->subcategory;
    $subcat = Category::where('parent_id','=',$m)->get();
    $daysOfWeek = unserialize(Event::find($id)->days_of_week);
    return view('event.edit',compact('event','s','subcat','subid','r','daysOfWeek','m'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your Controller method `edit()`

Your code:

```
$s = Category::all()->where('parent_id','=','0'); // wrong
```

Isn't that supposed to be:

```
$s = Category::where('parent_id','=','0')->get(); // correct
```

You are already fetching the categories with `all`, and then passing the `where` condition, hence it is not showing you the results. `where` condition returns the `instance` of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and not the desired results.

Update the wrong line with the correct one and the result should appear as you want.

Comment: Ok. i did what you said, but that is not my issue, when i press edit button, i am not getting values stored in database as selected value for dropdown. What can i do for that?

Comment: Replace select with the following: `{{ Form::select('category', $s->toArray(), null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) }}`